# Looping through integer in mustache, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, mustache, ractivejs

I have this object.

```
{
    "myValue": 5
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to loop from 1...5 in mustache templates? Like this:

```
{{#myValue}}
    {{.}}
{{/myValue}}
```

Prints:

```
12345
```

Comment: Imo, this shouldnt be possible. The view described by the template represents your data, and your data is not an array but an integer.  An obvious solution would be to change the data to { "myValue" : [1,2,3,4,5] } before binding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @Thaylon's comment, you need an array to iterate through rather than a number. But  assuming that changing `myValue` from `5` to `[1,2,3,4,5]` isn't an option, you can add a helper function that you can use in your template:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    myValue: 5,
    range: function ( low, high ) {
      var range = [];
      for ( i = low; i <= high; i += 1 ) {
        range.push( i );
      }
      return range;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
  {{#each range(1, myValue)}}
    <p>{{this}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

As an alternative to putting the `range()` helper on the `data` object, you could add it as a generic helper by doing something like this:

```js
var helpers = Ractive.defaults.data;

helpers.range = function ( low, high ) {
  var range = [];
  for ( i = low; i <= high; i += 1 ) {
    range.push( i );
  }
  return range;
};

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    myValue: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var sampleVal = '{{foo}}';
    // or var sampleVal = '{{foo.foo}}'; 
    for (var i = 0; i < sampleVal; i++) { 

    } 
</script>
```